# Una pregunta acerca del siguiente código en Python del Algoritmo de Dijkstra

Tags: python

es mi primera pregunta en este foro y me surgio una duda con este código, aclaro que yo no lo hice, fue encontrado en internet pero creo que es fácil de entender, se trata del algoritmo de Dijkstra para el problema de la ruta más corta dada una matriz de adyacencia.

```py
class Graph:

    def minDistance(self, dist, queue):
        minimum = float("Inf")
        min_index = -1

        for i in range(len(dist)):
            if dist[i] < minimum and i in queue:
                minimum = dist[i]
                min_index = i
        return min_index

    def printPath(self, parent, j):

        # Base Case : If j is source
        if parent[j] == -1:
            print (j),
            return
        self.printPath(parent, parent[j])
        print (j),

    def printSolution(self, dist, parent):
        src = 0
        print("Vertex \t\tDistance from Source\tPath")
        for i in range(1, len(dist)):
            print("\n%d --> %d \t\t%d \t\t\t\t\t" % (src, i, dist[i])),
            self.printPath(parent, i)

    def dijkstra(self, graph, src):

        row = len(graph)
        col = len(graph[0])

        dist = [float("Inf")] * row

        parent = [-1] * row

        dist[src] = 0

        queue = []
        for i in range(row):
            queue.append(i)

        while queue:
            u = self.minDistance(dist, queue)
            queue.remove(u)
            for i in range(col):
                if graph[u][i] and i in queue:
                    if dist[u] + graph[u][i] < dist[i]:
                        dist[i] = dist[u] + graph[u][i]
                        parent[i] = u


        self.printSolution(dist, parent)


g = Graph()

graph = [[0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
         [4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0],
         [0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2],
         [0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 4, 14, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6],
         [8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7],
         [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0]]

g.dijkstra(graph, 0)
```

Obteniendo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se ve la ruta que se sigue de nodo a nodo desde el origen y además el valor de la distancia de la ruta.

Todo esta bien cuando los valores de la matriz son enteros, pero cuando modifico estos valores a tipo flotante, por ejemplo la siguiente matriz

```py
graph = [[ 0.    9.37  5.35  7.57 15.7],
         [ 9.37  0.    9.62  6.01 19.62],
         [ 5.35  9.62  0.  11.02 21.03],
         [ 7.57  6.01 11.02  0.   13.61],
         [15.7  19.62 21.03 13.61  0.]]
```

Obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, los valores de la distancia me los redondea a 9, 5, 7 y 15 respectivamente, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que no me los redondee, en este caso me gustaria que se mantuvieran en punto decimal pero no veo como puedo hacerlo. He estado modificando algunas cosas del codigo, pero sigue dandome valores enteros y no veo que puedo hacer, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

La liga del código usado es esta:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-paths-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El algoritmo en realidad funciona para distancias no enteras, pues no hay ningún lugar en el código en que se redondeen o cambien a tipo `int` los datos de la matriz.

El único problema es que a la hora de imprimir las distancias, se usa `%d` para mostrar su valor, y esta cadena de formato significa "mostrar como entero".

Basta que lo cambies por `%g` para que ya muestre los decimales. En la línea de `printSolution()` que señalo seguidamente:

```
    def printSolution(self, dist, parent):
        src = 0
        print("Vertex \t\tDistance from Source\tPath")
        for i in range(1, len(dist)):
            print("\n%d --> %d \t\t%g \t\t\t\t\t" % (src, i, dist[i])),  # <---
            self.printPath(parent, i)
```

Con la matriz de distancias que propones, sale esto:

```
Vertex          Distance from Source    Path

0 --> 1                 9.37 
0
1

0 --> 2                 5.35 
0
2

0 --> 3                 7.57 
0
3

0 --> 4                 15.7 
0
4
```

Comment: Ahora lo veo, vaya, muchas gracias!